How to apply a date input mask using QuestPDF in ASP.NET?
In my asp.net application, I am using QuestPDF to generate PDF. But I am unable to generate date input mask within text. I can generate this if it is not within text. as it is a part of the text, that's why I can not generate if.
I already generated this

But can not generate this

Here is the code by which I have genearted the first one.
page.Footer().Column(col =>
{
   col.Item().Row(row =>
   {
      row.RelativeItem(0.73f).Row(innerRow =>
      {
         innerRow.AutoItem().Text("Dated this").FontSize(10);
         innerRow.ConstantItem(65).PaddingTop(7, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innserCol =>
         {
            innserCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.05f);
            innserCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("day of month").FontSize(10);
         });
         innerRow.AutoItem().Text("day of").FontSize(10);
         innerRow.ConstantItem(80).PaddingTop(7, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innserCol =>
         {
            innserCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.05f);
            innserCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("month").FontSize(10);
         });
         innerRow.AutoItem().Text(" ' ").FontSize(10);
         innerRow.ConstantItem(35).PaddingTop(7, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innserCol =>
         {
            innserCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.05f);
            innserCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("year").FontSize(10);
         });
         innerRow.AutoItem().Text(" ' at").FontSize(10);
         innerRow.ConstantItem(60).PaddingTop(7, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innserCol =>
         {
            innserCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.05f);
            innserCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("time of day").FontSize(10);
         });
         innerRow.AutoItem().MinimalBox().Width(12, Unit.Point).Height(12, Unit.Point).Border(0.5f, Unit.Point);
         innerRow.AutoItem().PaddingLeft(5, Unit.Point).Text("am").FontSize(10).FontColor(Colors.Black);
         innerRow.AutoItem().PaddingLeft(8, Unit.Point).MinimalBox().Width(12, Unit.Point).Height(12, Unit.Point).Border(0.5f, Unit.Point);
         innerRow.AutoItem().PaddingLeft(5, Unit.Point).Text("pm").FontSize(10).FontColor(Colors.Black);
      });

      row.RelativeItem(0.02f);

      row.RelativeItem(0.25f).Column(col =>
      {
         col.Item().AlignLeft().Text("Signature").FontSize(10);
         col.Item().Height(25, Unit.Point);
         col.Item().LineHorizontal(0.05f);
      });
   });
});

Here is the code and output by which I am trying to generate the 2nd one
Code:
col.Item().Row(row =>
{
   row.RelativeItem(0.73f).Row(innerRow =>
   {
      innerRow.RelativeItem()
          .AlignLeft()
          .Text(text =>
          {
             text.Span("I (we) appoint the proxy named in row A below, or, failing him or her, the proxy named in row B below, to attend and vote on my (our) behalf at the meeting of owners to be held on ")
 .FontSize(11);

             text.Element().Row(dateRow =>
             {
                dateRow.ConstantItem(40).PaddingTop(2, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innerCol =>
                {
                   innerCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.5f);
                   innerCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("yyyy").FontSize(10);
                });

                dateRow.AutoItem().Text("/").FontSize(11);

                dateRow.ConstantItem(30).PaddingTop(2, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innerCol =>
                {
                   innerCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.5f);
                   innerCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("mm").FontSize(10);
                });

                dateRow.AutoItem().Text("/").FontSize(11);

                dateRow.ConstantItem(30).PaddingTop(2, Unit.Millimetre).Column(innerCol =>
                {
                   innerCol.Item().LineHorizontal(0.5f);
                   innerCol.Item().AlignCenter().Text("dd").FontSize(10);
                });
             });

             text.Span(", and at any adjournment of the meeting:").FontSize(11);
          });
   });

   row.RelativeItem(0.02f);

   row.RelativeItem(0.25f);
});

Output:

It will be very kind, if anyone can help.
I tried for a long time with different code, but all went in vain.

Hi Alien, please try this code and tell us the result.

Hi @JasonPan , I’ve updated the question with your code, replacing the second code snippet and adding the output. It’s still not exactly what I’m looking for. I don't want a / in the mask; instead, I’m aiming for a solid mask. Additionally, there isn’t enough space to manually write a date when printing out the PDF.
